# why does Flurry analytics required android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE

Tags: android, flurry, android-permissions

I am using Flurry analytics in my android application
I get this Flurry exception on application startup

`E/FlurryAgent(4466): java.lang.SecurityException: ConnectivityService: Neither user 10059 nor current process has android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE.`

i get this exception when making this call
from the OnStart() method
`FlurryAgent.onStartSession(this, FLURRY_TOKEN);` 
I cannot find any mention of Flurry requiring this "uses permission"
why is this happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well because it will check the state of the network connection and avoid doing a network operation if there is no internet access (no wifi and 3g).

Answer (score 0):

It's required by Flurry SDK documentation.

http://support.flurry.com/index.php?title=Guides/f/Publishers/Code/Interstitials/Android

Question **"why?"** can initiate long discussion, so let's replace **"why?"** with **"MUST"** and this can close this shorter :)

Comment: plausible answer IF i was implementing Flurry Ads: I am not. Just Flurry analytics. I cannot find anywhere in FLURRY ANALYTICS anywhere that mentions that a required permission is network state

Comment: ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE is very useful perission. For example, they can try to send throw wifi instead of 3G making stats of actual connections. It's the first possible case easy coming in mind.

Comment: Note that while it is on *that* page of the documentation, it is not on other pages e.g. http://support.flurry.com/index.php?title=Analytics/GettingStarted/TechnicalQuickStart/Android